# How to use GridSearchCV for tuning parameters with train_test_split strategy?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, train-test-split, gridsearchcv

I am trying to fine tune my sklearn models using train_test_split strategy. I am aware of [GridSearchCV](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html)'s ability to perform parameter tuning, however, it was tied to using Cross Validation strategy, I would like to use train_test_split strategy for the parameter searching, for the speed of training is important for my case, I prefer simple [train_test_split](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) over cross-validation.

I could try to write my own for loop, but it would be inefficient for not taking advantage of the built-in parallelization used in GridSearchCV.

Anyone knows how to take advantage GridSearchCV for this? Or provide an alternative that wasn't too slow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can use [ShuffleSplit](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.ShuffleSplit.html) for this.

ShuffleSplit is a cross validation strategy like `KFold`, but unlike `KFold` where you have to train `K` models, here you can control how many times to do the train/test split, even once if you prefer.

```
shuffle_split = ShuffleSplit(n_splits=1,test_size=.25)
```

`n_splits` defines how many times to repeat this splitting and training routine.
Now you can use it like this:

```
GridSearchCV(clf,param_grid={},cv=shuffle_split)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add on to Shihab Shahriar's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57675698/10281627), by providing a code sample.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV, ShuffleSplit
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

# Load iris dataset
iris = datasets.load_iris()

# Prepare X and y as dataframe
X = pd.DataFrame(data=iris.data, columns=iris.feature_names)
y = pd.DataFrame(data=iris.target, columns=['Species'])

# Train test split
shuffle_split = ShuffleSplit(n_splits=1, test_size=0.3)
# This is equivalent to: 
#   X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3)
# But, it is usable for GridSearchCV

# GridSearch without CV
params = { 'n_estimators': [16, 32] }
clf = RandomForestClassifier()
grid_search = GridSearchCV(clf, param_grid=params, cv=shuffle_split)
grid_search.fit(X, y)
```

This should help anyone facing a similar problem.